# Avoid generating nested iterators and then immediately unpacking them

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my some code I'm working on, I'm handling generating a lot of one-level deep nested iterators that need to be combined. As a working solution, I've wrapped each of these parts in `chain(*(one_level_nested))` (where `chain` is from the well-loved [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module). However, repeating this expression several times makes me feel this expression is ugly and possibly misguided;

As an example of the one level deep generation code, most of them are constructed the following way: `[j for j in something_needing_i(i)] for i in range(5)` Thus I end up with `chain(*([j for j in something_needing_i(i)] for i in range(5)))`.

Is there a better approach, specifically in terms of generating the iterator without unpacking and with comparable efficiency (or ideally, better efficiency)?

Comment: Use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Actually, while my examples shows a list comprehension instead of a generator expression, I was actually using generator expressions in the original code. Whoops. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the following nesting:

```
(j for i in range(5) for j in something_needing_i(i))
```

in order to get a flat generator. This also avoids the spurious intermediate lists for better space efficiency.

The order of the two `for` constructs may seem counter-intuitive at first as you have to turn them around in comparison to the one creating nested generators/lists. Also, their scoping does not correspond to my natural language "feel", but that's the way they work.

Comment: It's the order you would use for nested loops if you were to write them out.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am well aware =) it is still not the order you use to create nested generators. And in nested loops, the thing happening in the innermost loop comes *after* (inside) the loops, whereas here, the expression being yielded comes *before* them, moving one `j` away from the other which in NLP, would correspond to moving a node from its original place in the syntax tree.

Comment: The order is very counter-intuitive for me. I think the counter-intuitive part is that the left side is the result, where in an actual for-loop, the right side would be the result. But once you get past that, it makes a lot of sense. Also, for completeness, looking at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) probably could have cleared things up for me, but it didn't occur to me before asking. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: ordering of operations is always right to left, not the other way around. if I want to asign 5 to a , i write a = 5. If I first want to multiply by 3 I write a = 5 * 3. If I first want to convert the string 3 to an int I write a =  5 * int('3')

Comment: @MarcWagner What about `a = 5 - 3 + 2`

Comment: @MarcWagner The only thing you've shown is that *name binding* is right-to-left. Every other example you've given seems mistaken or trivially reduces to name binding: `5 * 3 == 3 * 5` and `5 * int('3') == int('3') * 5` because multiplication is commutative in both of these examples.